# Android layouts for same density different diagonal length

Tags: android

I have 2 different android phones.  The details are

nexus s: 480 x 800 pixels, 4.0 inches (~233 ppi pixel density)
desire s: 480 x 800 pixels, 3.70 inches (~252 ppi pixel density)

Now I have my layout folders as layout_hdpi and layout_xhdpi. Now both these phones are classes as hdpi phones. I have a controls with a padding of 5dip to the left and the right. But on these phones the 5dip translates to different widths hence the border on one phone is fatter then on the second phone. Increasing one also increases the other. Can someone help me please?

Comment: can you share the both screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for different screen sizes use relative-layouts.. it will not cause the problem of different width on different phones

Answer (score 1):

First of all `layout_hdpi` and `layout_xhdpi` should be declared as `layout-hdpi` and `layout-xhdpi`.
Secondly, HDPI refers to the range 161–240(ppi). So your Nexus phone is eligible for the HDPI qualifier, but your Desire S is eligible for XHDPI qualifier, because the range of xhdpi is 241–319.