# android how to support multiple screen

Tags: android, screen

Thais is what I have done. I try to support this screen sizes:

```
xlarge screens 640dp x 960dp
large screens 480dp x 800dp
normal screens 320dp x 400dp
small screens 240dp x 400dp
```

So I create etc. background images with that sizes (640dp x 960dp, 480dp x 800dp, 320dp x 400dp and 240 x 400). I put images in folders drawabale-xhdpi, drawabale-hdpi, drawabale-mdpi and drawabale-ldpi.
When I have xlarge screen with hdpi density (it use images from hdpi folder), graphic is bad (images are not large enough). So how to use that xlarge image when I have hdpi density. Do I have to create more images and put them in some places? This is a game, I draw all in canvas, don't use layouts for drawing images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new drawables in a `drawable-xlarge-hdpi` folder

Comment: I am not sure is this what you mean. Do I need to create drawable-xlarge-ldpi, drawable-xlarge-mdpi, drawable-xlarge-hdpi-hdpi, drawable-xlarge-hdpi-xhdpi and all that for large, normal and small? Can I just create (drawable-xlarge, drawable-large, drawable-normal and drawable-small) and put my images in that 4 folders?

Comment: if you want to use specific resources for a very specific device(specified screen size and density), you will need to create drawable-xlarge-ldpi(not sur if a ldpi tablet exist), drawable-xlarge-mdpi(most of android tablet), drawable-xlarge-hdpi(a very few tablet) and drawable-xlarge-xhdpi(not sure if a tablet like this exist).

Comment: if I have a png image with 50*50 px size on drawable-mdpi,what is size for xlarge-xhdpi drawable?

Answer (score 0):

use this path to save your image

```
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Check this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more clarifications of multiple screen support.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link - [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

You can have an image in **drawable-xlarge-hdpi** folder

Answer (score -1):

always use relative layouts to support multiple screens. see here [Android layouts for same density different diagonal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673605/android-layouts-for-same-density-different-diagonal-length/12674393#12674393)

Comment: This is totally wrong!
Read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html